# How to map multiple request using collections

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a time request from multiple time inputs

```
<form>
    ...
    <input type="text" name="times[]">
    <input type="text" name="times[]">
    ...
</form>
```

And in my controller `dd($request->times)` returns

```
array:3 [
  0 => "2:25 AM"
  1 => "5:35 AM"
  2 => "5:40 AM"
]
```

How can I map this request using laravel collection into this

```
[
    [
        'time' => '2:25 AM',
    ],
    [
        'time' => '5:35 AM',
    ],
    [
        'time' => '5:40 AM',
    ],
]
```

I tried this

```
$timesArray = collect([$request->times]);
$times = $timesArray->mapWithKeys(function ($item, $key) {
    return [ 'time' => $item[$key] ];
})->toArray();
```

But it only return

```
array:1 [
  "time" => "2:25 AM"
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need nested structure. Since in same array or collection there will be only one value associated with single key `time`

Comment: And how can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `mapWithKeys`, you are trying to map array values without keys, so [`map`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-map) will do.

```
$times = collect($request->times)
    ->map(function ($time) {
        return [ 'time' => $time ];
    })
    ->toArray();
```

Also, `$request->times` is already an array, so you don't have to wrap this in square brackets again or you are creating an array in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$timesArray = [];
foreach($request->times as $time){
    $timesArray[] = ['time' => $time];
}
```

Comment: it returns this error `(1/1) FatalErrorException Cannot use empty list`

Comment: i have a typo $timesArray-[] change to $timesArray[] =

Comment: Now it is working. I would accept your answer. But I need a laravel Solution. Thanks.